# passing an object(s) to be serialised java

Tags: java, arrays, object, serialization

I have scoured many web pages trying to solve this issue, but I am struggling. I don't want someone to fix it for me, I just want someone to point me in the right direction please :).
 My problem is two-fold, I have an array of objects,I want to pass each object to my Teams class, so that the team name can be saved. This code doesn't compile, error concerns line:
 "Teams(MainmenuTest[]) teamName() {"

error is '.class' expected
followed by
';' expected

I can get serialisation to work when the objects are created in my Teams class, (if I comment out the code for passing objects), and it does create a .ser file in the directory I have specified.

Here are the snippets of code:

```
public class Teams implements java.io.Serializable{

  public Teams(){

    // constructor
    MainmenuTest[] teamName;
    Teams(MainmenuTest[]) teamName() {
      this.teamName = teamName;
    }
  }



   public String name;
   public String address;
   public transient int SSN;
   public int number;
   public void mailCheck()
   {
      System.out.println("Mailing a check to " + name + " " + address);
   }
} // end Teams class



public class premierLeagueClubs{

  public String club;
  Teams[] teamName = new Teams[19];
  premierLeagueClubs f = new premierLeagueClubs();
  Teams t = new Teams(f,teamName);


public String arsenal(){

  teamName[0].club = "Arsenal";

System.out.println("You are the new manager of" + club);
return club;
} // end method arsenal
```

Here is the MainmenuTest code:

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainmenuTest extends premierLeagueClubs{



int choice;

public MainmenuTest(){

//constructor
}


public static void main(String args[]){

    MainmenuTest team = new MainmenuTest();

team.getInput();



  } // end main method
```

Comment: Check the parenthesis.

Comment: You cannot put a constructor inside another objects constructor